# Load testing is possible in ipad or iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, testing

I am new to automation testing for iOS. I am trying to test one app that have number of users. Users requires to login to the app for further access. So i just want to test that how many users at a time can login to app. and App is available for ipad.

Anyone can suggest automation tool for iOS ?

Comment: That's going to depend how you implement your app. You can only have one user using an ipad at a time, so therefore you can only have one user at a time using your app. To have more than one user logged in at a time doesn't make sense.

Comment: I would assume load testing the web server behind the app is what you would want to be doing

Comment: yes exactly want to test server behind this app..but want to test it on ipad